# Where is the home folder for local accounts - Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I created 2 Local accounts on my Windows 8 PC.

I don't see a separate Home folders for BOTH the accounts in C:\Users.

When i type cmd in the run dialog, to see the current windows home, im taken to the home folder of the very first microsoft account which I created when I installed windows 8.

Whats going on here?

Comment: You're leaving out WAY too much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you login using those two accounts? Alteast in Windows 7, the folders for local accounts are not created till you:

1. Log-in into the OS using that account
2. Some service runs under that account (That will indirectly cause the user profile to be loaded leading to the local user folders to be created.